# Cloudfront caching react website pages despite using file versioning

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache

So to explain a problem I have a static website hosted on s3 and CloudFront as the CDN. I have used create-react-app(CRA) to create the react package for my website. CRA by default does versioning of webpack build files and the versions are visible in the s3 bucket as well.
Still when I do a deployment, the latest changes don't come up(I have waited even a day hoping it would come). I am not sure what is causing this issue. Can anyone please help.

I have added the screenshots of my cloudfront behaviour tab and the s3 bucket files having build versions.

Ps, If it is the case of browser cache how can I disable it so that my clients always see the most latest version of my website.

[image: Cloud front behaviour screen shot]

[image: S3 versioned files]

Comment: Are you sure your HTML is not being cached, these are all unique objects from what I can see so the new objects should not be cached

Comment: @ChrisWilliams But my react components render the html. Is it possible that rendered html can be cached too?

Comment: There will still be a page that calls the react libraries or includes, this is what will potentially be cached. If you check the response of your page it will have cache headers including max-age. These will be cached in the users browser if they're set

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Can you help me with how to find the "response of page" and cache headers. I havent setup any headers to be sent from s3 and use custom object caching(as shown in the first picture)

Comment: In your browser you should be able to inspect network traffic, for example in chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to invalidate cache in the distribution settings tab. I ideally invalidate all cache by passing /* or you can also specify folder or file to clear cacheing.
example: /index.html

Even in your CI/CD pools line you can ask deploy agent to invalidate cache by passing distribution ID and path